# How do I avoid scriptslauncher.bat: command not found error running Java in VS Code?

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

[image]

Currently getting an error `c:Usersslbut.vscodeextensionsvscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.29.0scriptslauncher.bat: command not found` , but when I go to that location I see the bat file visible.  Not sure how to stop this from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a issue about [file .bat command not found](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/708) post in Github, and it's because .bat files can't be launched in wsl terminal. Switching to **cmd** instead of using wsl as default terminal can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wsl as default shell and still run your java projects by using the internal console.

You can set it under user settings in Code.

Ctrl-Shift-P -> Preferences: Open User Setting -> Edit setting.json

Add the line

```
"java.debug.settings.console": "internalConsole",
```